# How to remove non-english from the textual data in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, character-encoding

I am cleaning the textual data that I scrawled from multiple urls. How can I remove non-English words/symbols from the data in a csv file?

I saved the data and read the data using the following codes:

To save the data as csv file:

```
df.to_csv("blogdata.csv", encoding = "utf-8")
```

After saving the data, the csv file shows as follows including non-English words and symbols (e.g., '\n\t\t\t', mâ€™, etc.):

[image]

The symbols did not show in the original data and some of them even appear from the data that are in English. Take 'Ross Parker' in the 7th row as an example.

The data saved in the csv file says: ['\n\t\t\t', 'Itâ€™s about time I wrote an update on what weâ€™ve been up to over the past few months. Weâ€™re about to...

Where in the original data scrawled from the url, it shows as follows:

[image]

Can anybody explain why this happens and help me solve this issue and clean the non-English data from the file?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What are you view the Csv file with ???; If Excel how did you import the data ??

Comment: Probably a much better fix would be to fix the crawler so it only picks out the text you actually want extracted. We can't really guess from the sample you show.

Comment: Encoding errors can never be resolved completely automatically, but this one looks like UTF-8 which was encoded into Latin-1 by mistake. Simply try decoding from Latin-1 to UTF-8; if it succeeds, the original text almost certainly contained mojibake.

Comment: Thank you all. @tripleee How can I decode from Latin-1 to UTF-8?

Comment: `text = text.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` should produce a string with the mojibake reverted if it succeeds. If you get a `UnicodeDecodeError` it means that `text`  did not have this specific kind of mojibake in the first place.

Comment: But whatever produced the "original data" seems to have rendered it correctly. Perhaps you are just viewing the CSV in a tool which assumes the data is in Latin-1, when it's actually completely correct UTF-8?

Comment: @BruceMartin It is the csv file in excel. This code df.to_csv("blogdata.csv", encoding = "utf-8") is the one that I used to save the data as a csv file.  To read the data back, I used this: blogdata = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/hyoungm/Downloads/blogdata2.csv')

Comment: It might be easier to work with xlsx files instead of csv. xlsx files retain important metadata such as column types and don't need the character encoding communicated separately.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pilot error: the data is correct but you are looking at it in a tool which is configured or hard-coded to display the text as Latin-1 (or Windows code page 1252?) even though you saved it as UTF-8.

Some tools - epecially on Windows - will do whimsical things with UTF-8 which doesn't have a BOM. Maybe try adding one (and maybe file a bug report if this really helps; the tool should at the very least let you override its default encoding, without modifying the input data).

In other words, if the screen shot with the broken data is from Excel, you probably selected a DOS oode page (or the horribly mislabelled "ANSI") instead of UTF-8 when it asked how to import this CSV file. Perhaps the best fix would be to devise a workflow which does not involve a spreadsheet.

Or perhaps you used a tool which didn't ask you anything, and tried to "sniff" the data to determine its encoding, and it guessed wrong. Adding an invisible byte sequence called a BOM which is unique to UTF-8 should hopefully allow it to guess right; but this is buggy behavior - you should not be a hostage to its clearly imperfect heuristics. (See also *["Bush hid the facts"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts)* for a related story.)

Comment: Thank you for your more information about the data. I am sorry but am a computer dummy, so not quite understand all your explanation. May the code suggested by you above help read the data correctly?

Comment: I also had another quick question. How can I remove '\n\t\t\t' only in the brackets? I want other textual data remain but want to remove this part only.

Comment: @HyoungeunMoon If your question was more specific about how exactly you got to this point, it would be easier to explain what you might want to try to do differently. But I'll add a speculation.

Comment: `item = item.lstrip('\n\t')` will strip `\n` and `\t` characters from the left of `item`; but again, you might want to fix this already in the crawler. And a comment is not really the right place to ask an unrelated follow-up question.